# Jpa Persistence context visibility

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, web

IS persistence context is shared by all user using jpa based application or for each user seperate perisistence context is created for web based application..?

Answer (score 0):

persistence context is bound to the transaction or the stateful bean, and each user has separate persistence context in web-based application usually. In common case, his every http-request to application will create the new context if necessary

Comment: What happens in stateless bean?

Comment: Within JavaEE environment PersistenceContext is created lazy by the container during a transaction (when you call some bean method) and will be closed when the transaction completes.